# multiplication between columns on different files

Tags: awk

I am using the following line

```
awk '{if (FNR==90307) for(i=2;i<=10;i+=3) print " x=", x=$i," y=", y=$(i+1), "z=", z=$(i+2) }' coord.xvg veloc.xvg force.xvg
```

This script outputs the xyz from each file xvg.

```
x= 5.78201  y= 6.72302 z= 7.07345
 x= 5.81603  y= 6.76299 z= 6.94258
 x= 5.70397  y= 6.75502 z= 6.85738
 x= -3.29165e-05  y= -3.86794e-05 z= 0.000126634 
 x= -1.77439e-05  y= 3.28865e-05 z= -0.000156011 
 x= -1.52779e-05  y= -9.56992e-05 z= 0.000427172 
 x= 6.30622  y= 86.4321 z= 51.1683 
 x= 55.7424  y= 26.0566 z= 76.0063
 x= -459.011  y= 19.386 z= 302.62
```

the question is that in the same do-loop (current frame, ) , can i do the following multiplication

```
i=2
(x(2) from force.xvg) X (y(2) from coord.xvg) 

i=3
(x(3) from force.xvg) X (y(3) from coord.xvg) 
i=4
```

…..
….
….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test:

```
awk '
    FNR == 90307 {
        for (n=2; n<=10; n+=3) {
            i=(n+1)/3
            x[i,FILENAME] = $n
            y[i,FILENAME] = $(n+1)
            z[i,FILENAME] = $(n+2)
            print FILENAME, i, " x=", $n," y=", $(n+1), "z=", $(n+2) 
        }
    }
    END {
        print "the products:"
        for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            print i, x[i,"force.xvg"] * y[i,"coord.xvg"]
        }
    }
' coord.xvg veloc.xvg force.xvg
```

The key points here:

- `FILENAME` is an awk variable holding the name of the current input file
- awk can do pseudo-multidimensional arrays (here `i` and `FILENAME` are concatenated with the `SUBSEP` variable)

  - nawk and gawk implement this, other awks I can't speak to.

Comment: All modern awks will support pseudo-multidimensional arrays. Only old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris) won't and that's because it's, well, old and broken.

Comment: If I want to do this for every line what should i do? For instance FNR ==90308, 90309 etc